# How to count the number of campaigns per day based on the start and end dates of the campaigns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, databricks-sql

I need to count the number of campaigns per day based on the start and end dates of the campaigns

**Input Table:**

| Campaign name | Start date | End date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign A | 2022-07-10 | 2022-09-25 |
| Campaign B | 2022-08-06 | 2022-10-07 |
| Campaign C | 2022-07-30 | 2022-09-10 |
| Campaign D | 2022-08-26 | 2022-10-24 |
| Campaign E | 2022-07-17 | 2022-09-29 |
| Campaign F | 2022-08-24 | 2022-09-12 |
| Campaign G | 2022-08-11 | 2022-10-24 |
| Campaign H | 2022-08-26 | 2022-11-22 |
| Campaign I | 2022-08-29 | 2022-09-25 |
| Campaign J | 2022-08-21 | 2022-11-15 |
| Campaign K | 2022-07-20 | 2022-09-18 |
| Campaign L | 2022-07-31 | 2022-11-20 |
| Campaign M | 2022-08-17 | 2022-10-10 |
| Campaign N | 2022-07-27 | 2022-09-07 |
| Campaign O | 2022-07-29 | 2022-09-26 |
| Campaign P | 2022-07-06 | 2022-09-15 |
| Campaign Q | 2022-07-16 | 2022-09-22 |

Out needed **(result):**

| Date | Count unique campaigns |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-02 | 17 |
| 2022-07-03 | 47 |
| 2022-07-04 | 5 |
| 2022-07-05 | 5 |
| 2022-07-06 | 25 |
| 2022-07-07 | 27 |
| 2022-07-08 | 17 |
| 2022-07-09 | 58 |
| 2022-07-10 | 23 |
| 2022-07-11 | 53 |
| 2022-07-12 | 18 |
| 2022-07-13 | 29 |
| 2022-07-14 | 52 |
| 2022-07-15 | 7 |
| 2022-07-16 | 17 |
| 2022-07-17 | 37 |
| 2022-07-18 | 33 |

How do I need to write the **SQL** command to get the above result? thanks all

Comment: Are your desired results correct? What campaigns happened on 2022-07-02?

Comment: Also, are you using Microsoft SQL Server, or DataBricks? I don't think the same solution can work for both - you should tag one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following solutions we leverage `string_split` with combination with replicate to generate new records.

```
select   dt        as date
        ,count(*)  as Count_unique_campaigns

from      
(
select    *
         ,dateadd(day, row_number() over(partition by Campaign_name  order by (select null))-1, Start_date) as dt
from     (
         select   *
         from     t
         outer apply string_split(replicate(',',datediff(day, Start_date, End_date)),',')
         ) t
) t
group by dt
order by dt
```

| date | Count_unique_campaigns |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-06 | 1 |
| 2022-07-07 | 1 |
| 2022-07-08 | 1 |
| 2022-07-09 | 1 |
| 2022-07-10 | 2 |
| 2022-07-11 | 2 |
| 2022-07-12 | 2 |
| 2022-07-13 | 2 |
| 2022-07-14 | 2 |
| 2022-07-15 | 2 |
| 2022-07-16 | 3 |
| 2022-07-17 | 4 |
| 2022-07-18 | 4 |
| 2022-07-19 | 4 |
| 2022-07-20 | 5 |
| 2022-07-21 | 5 |
| 2022-07-22 | 5 |
| 2022-07-23 | 5 |
| 2022-07-24 | 5 |
| 2022-07-25 | 5 |
| 2022-07-26 | 5 |
| 2022-07-27 | 6 |
| 2022-07-28 | 6 |
| 2022-07-29 | 7 |
| 2022-07-30 | 8 |
| 2022-07-31 | 9 |
| 2022-08-01 | 9 |
| 2022-08-02 | 9 |
| 2022-08-03 | 9 |
| 2022-08-04 | 9 |
| 2022-08-05 | 9 |
| 2022-08-06 | 10 |
| 2022-08-07 | 10 |
| 2022-08-08 | 10 |
| 2022-08-09 | 10 |
| 2022-08-10 | 10 |
| 2022-08-11 | 11 |
| 2022-08-12 | 11 |
| 2022-08-13 | 11 |
| 2022-08-14 | 11 |
| 2022-08-15 | 11 |
| 2022-08-16 | 11 |
| 2022-08-17 | 12 |
| 2022-08-18 | 12 |
| 2022-08-19 | 12 |
| 2022-08-20 | 12 |
| 2022-08-21 | 13 |
| 2022-08-22 | 13 |
| 2022-08-23 | 13 |
| 2022-08-24 | 14 |
| 2022-08-25 | 14 |
| 2022-08-26 | 16 |
| 2022-08-27 | 16 |
| 2022-08-28 | 16 |
| 2022-08-29 | 17 |
| 2022-08-30 | 17 |
| 2022-08-31 | 17 |
| 2022-09-01 | 17 |
| 2022-09-02 | 17 |
| 2022-09-03 | 17 |
| 2022-09-04 | 17 |
| 2022-09-05 | 17 |
| 2022-09-06 | 17 |
| 2022-09-07 | 17 |
| 2022-09-08 | 16 |
| 2022-09-09 | 16 |
| 2022-09-10 | 16 |
| 2022-09-11 | 15 |
| 2022-09-12 | 15 |
| 2022-09-13 | 14 |
| 2022-09-14 | 14 |
| 2022-09-15 | 14 |
| 2022-09-16 | 13 |
| 2022-09-17 | 13 |
| 2022-09-18 | 13 |
| 2022-09-19 | 12 |
| 2022-09-20 | 12 |
| 2022-09-21 | 12 |
| 2022-09-22 | 12 |
| 2022-09-23 | 11 |
| 2022-09-24 | 11 |
| 2022-09-25 | 11 |
| 2022-09-26 | 9 |
| 2022-09-27 | 8 |
| 2022-09-28 | 8 |
| 2022-09-29 | 8 |
| 2022-09-30 | 7 |
| 2022-10-01 | 7 |
| 2022-10-02 | 7 |
| 2022-10-03 | 7 |
| 2022-10-04 | 7 |
| 2022-10-05 | 7 |
| 2022-10-06 | 7 |
| 2022-10-07 | 7 |
| 2022-10-08 | 6 |
| 2022-10-09 | 6 |
| 2022-10-10 | 6 |
| 2022-10-11 | 5 |
| 2022-10-12 | 5 |
| 2022-10-13 | 5 |
| 2022-10-14 | 5 |
| 2022-10-15 | 5 |
| 2022-10-16 | 5 |
| 2022-10-17 | 5 |
| 2022-10-18 | 5 |
| 2022-10-19 | 5 |
| 2022-10-20 | 5 |
| 2022-10-21 | 5 |
| 2022-10-22 | 5 |
| 2022-10-23 | 5 |
| 2022-10-24 | 5 |
| 2022-10-25 | 3 |
| 2022-10-26 | 3 |
| 2022-10-27 | 3 |
| 2022-10-28 | 3 |
| 2022-10-29 | 3 |
| 2022-10-30 | 3 |
| 2022-10-31 | 3 |
| 2022-11-01 | 3 |
| 2022-11-02 | 3 |
| 2022-11-03 | 3 |
| 2022-11-04 | 3 |
| 2022-11-05 | 3 |
| 2022-11-06 | 3 |
| 2022-11-07 | 3 |
| 2022-11-08 | 3 |
| 2022-11-09 | 3 |
| 2022-11-10 | 3 |
| 2022-11-11 | 3 |
| 2022-11-12 | 3 |
| 2022-11-13 | 3 |
| 2022-11-14 | 3 |
| 2022-11-15 | 3 |
| 2022-11-16 | 2 |
| 2022-11-17 | 2 |
| 2022-11-18 | 2 |
| 2022-11-19 | 2 |
| 2022-11-20 | 2 |
| 2022-11-21 | 1 |
| 2022-11-22 | 1 |

For SQL in Azure and SQL Server 2022 we have a cleaner solution based on [ordinal][4].

> "The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently
> supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure
> Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only). Beginning with SQL
> Server 2022 (16.x) Preview, the argument and output column are
> available in SQL Server."

```
select   dt        as date
        ,count(*)  as Count_unique_campaigns

from      
(
select    *
         ,dateadd(day, ordinal-1, Start_date) as dt
from     (
         select   *
         from     t
         outer apply string_split(replicate(',',datediff(day, Start_date, End_date)),',', 1)
         ) t
) t
group by dt
order by dt
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BDUbH2NB)

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data doesn't seem to match your desired results, but I *think* what you're after is this:

```
DECLARE @Start date, @End date;

-- first, find the earliest and last date:

SELECT @Start = MIN([Start date]), @End = MAX([End date])
  FROM dbo.Campaigns;

-- now use a recursive CTE to build a date range, 
-- and count the number of campaigns that have a row
-- where the campaign was active on that date:

WITH d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT @Start 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, d) FROM d WHERE d < @End
)
SELECT 
  [Date] = d, 
  [Count unique campaigns] = COUNT(*) 
FROM d 
INNER JOIN dbo.Campaigns AS c
ON d.d >= c.[Start date] AND d.d <= c.[End date]
GROUP BY d.d OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

Working example in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/01qoMmR3).